# RCPTT preference is not applied upon eclipse launch

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rcptt

My eclipse plugin app has a background job running at the background which launches the dialog as soon as the eclipse is launched.

When launching the eclipse from RCPTT tool, I would like to disable the dialog prompt as this causes our existing test suites to fail.

To get rid of the issue, I had tried disabling the preference property `XXX.autoStart=false` in the preference settings. It is not having immediate effect in the launched instance of eclipse and we will need to restart or re-execute the test suite in order to make it work.

Is there any way to suppress the dialog prompt at eclipse application startup through RCPTT preference ?

P.S. I have gone through the link https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/contexts/preferences/
but that doesn't seem to help!

Answer (score 0):

You need two contexts to do so, for example:

-`PREF_Disable_dialog`: A preferences context which sets the `XXX.autoStart=false` property

-`ECL_restart`: An Eclipse Command Line script, holding two instructions:

```
restart-aut
wait-until-eclipse-is-ready
```

Add these two to the context of your test case(s), in the order above. The restart will be considered part of the test case, and you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Is there a way to set the preference without restart?  Restart is not a good practice and it's quite tedious.

Comment: Not that I know of. It is debatable whether restarting an application is good practice; it is slower to execute but can result in clearer test reports, as errors will not affect other cases so much.

Comment: That's ok.  I'm looking out for an approach that would basically enable the preference as soon as the eclipse gets launched.   Restarting every test case is cumbersome process and we have a test suite of 2000 test case.

Comment: And what if you only add the ECL_restart to the first Test Case of your Test Suites? I don't know how you schedule your RCPTT runs, but if you don't clear the preferences between Test Cases, then one (or a few) use of the restart will make cases pass on your CI server.